# standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Tags: docker, powerpc

I am trying to build kibana 7.6.0 image using centos:7 as the base image On PPC64LE architecture.

```
FROM centos:7 AS prep_files
COPY --from=prep_files --chown=1000:0 /usr/share/kibana /usr/share/kibana
COPY --chown=1000:0 bin/kibana-docker /usr/local/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/kibana-docker"]
```

The image was successfully built, however it gives the following error:

```
docker run -it kibana:7.6.0
standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

Docker:

```
Client:
Version:      18.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   ccde200
 Built:        Tue Jun  5 20:32:10 2018
 OS/Arch:      linux/ppc64le
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.03.1-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.5
  Git commit:   ccde200
  Built:        Tue Jun  5 20:35:04 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/ppc64le
  Experimental: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"exec format error"` is an indication that you are running a binary designed for another platform. You'll need to look at how you've compiled the `bin/kibana-docker` binary or possibly the `dumb-init` binary. On the host you can check this with `file bin/kibana-docker`.

Comment: yes. Using power specific dumb-init works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://github.com/containers/buildah/issues/475)

1. Add #!/bin/bash to my entry point file.
2. Upgrade runc.